# I want to compare the each value in a java map with another value

Tags: java, hashmap

If a value matches with another value then, i want to get the key,value pair corresponding to that value into a new map and values that doesn't match i.e unique key,value pairs into another map.

Eg:

```
Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();

map.put("First",123.12345); //data1
map.put("Second",234.3456); //data2
map.put("Third",576.9876); //data3
map.put("Fourth",123.12345);//data4
map.put("Fifth",234.3456); //data5
map.put("Sixth",999.8888); //data6
map.put("Seventh",677.4578); //data7
```

Now here (data1 and data4) values (data2 and data5) and  match and i want to store these (key,value) pairs in a new Map

Similarly data3, data and data7 have unique values and i want to store these (key,value) pairs in another new Map.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You grouping by the map value and collect those entry with same value into a Map.

```
Map<Double, Map<String, Double>> result = 
   map.entrySet().stream()
                 .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
```

This will give you result like:

```
{
   123.12345 -> {
       First -> 123.12345,
       Fourth -> 123.12345
   }, 
   234.3456 -> ...
}
```

**In java 7:**

```
Map<Double, Map<String, Double>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String, Double> mapping : map.entrySet()) {
    Double value = mapping.getValue();
    if (!result.containsKey(value)) {
        result.put(value, new HashMap<>());
    }
    // Add new pair to map
    result.get(value).put(mapping.getKey(), value);
}
```

Comment: i have tried the solution suggested as below

Map<Double, Map<String, Double>> result =  map.entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));

Iam gettting error at the point toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));

Could you please give a working solution with prints of the resultant map

Comment: You need to import appropriate class and methods. `groupingBy` is from `Collectors.groupingBy`. `Entry` is from `Map.Entry`

Comment: The solution proposed is in java8. Could any one please provide solution which can be achieved using java 7

Comment: You can easily translate it to jv7

Comment: Collectors class is not available in Java 7. So how can we translate?

Comment: Can u pls give the solution in java7